# Largest online database of quasicrystal

Tags: reference-request, tessellations

[This paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00150190108225104#preview) gives a [**broken** link](http://www.quasicrystal.ethz.ch/QDB) and Google was not of any help either yielding introductory materials on the subject. Anyone knows if the database (if it exists) has been moved to a new server and if so, what could be the URL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tilings Encyclopedia](http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/) is pretty useful. (Found the URL in a [quasicrystal video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjao3H4z7-g).)